# java properties

Tags: java, properties

With properties in java how could I check if the value of the property is equal to something example if the property quitonload is equal to true then the program will exit on start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or if you're using a Properties file you can do this:

```
Properties p = new Properties()

p.load(new FileInputStream(args[0]))

if (p.getProperty("quitonload").equals("true")) {
  System.out.println("quitonload is true");
  System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println("quitonload is false");
```

Check the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) on the Properties file if you have any doubts on the file format.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like:

```
if (System.getProperty("quitonload", "false").equals("true")) {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Note the quotation marks; system properties are always strings.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `System.exit()` will [terminate the entire JVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29), and is thus often considered bad practice.

Comment: I'd upvote, apart from the "System.exit(1);" - it's just too dangerous that this kind of code might end up in a library some day... One can get around it using a SecurityManager, but it's a pain to have to do so.

Comment: Why the '1' for the return code?  It seems like a normal application exit (based on the iota of information we have) to me.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: yes, you're right, I guess I was just way too tired when I wrote this.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are key/value pairs, each represented by a `String`

```
if (myPropertiesObj.getProperty("quitonload").equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
{
    ...
}
```